# AngularJS math joining strings instead of adding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a standard `$scope.totals = $scope.totals = {storage:0, dailystorage:0};` and an `angular.forEach` that adds `cam.storage` to the `$scope.totals.storage` to give me the total storage.

I am using this to do that:

```
$scope.totals.storage = $scope.totals.storage+cam.storage;
```

The problem is that, say if two `cam.storage` are `21.09` and `15.82`, it'll make `$scope.totals.storage` `21.0915.82` - basically adding them like strings instead of like math.

How do I make it an addition - not a joining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you've posted (verifying that `$scope.totals` is already a number), `cam.storage` is a string. You need to parse it to a number before adding it to the existing value:

```
$scope.totals.storage += parseFloat(cam.storage);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm going to choose this one because it's the cleanest of the options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If they are concatenating instead of adding, it sounds like you need to parse them as decimals (You can also use `toFixed(int)` to limit the decimals as needed).

```
$scope.totals.storage = parseFloat($scope.totals.storage)+parseFloat(cam.storage);
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution I use {{(a*1)+(b*1)}} It work.